# Changing the elements of a C-style array in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to change the elements of a C-style array. Using an `NSArray`/`NSMutableArray` is not an option for me.

My code is as so:

```
int losingPositionsX[] = {0, 4, 8...};
```

but when I enter this code

```
losingPositionsX = {8, 16, 24};
```

to change the arrays elements of he array it has an error of: "expected expression" How can I make the copy?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use something like `memcpy()` or a loop.

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 3
const int VALUES[ARRAY_SIZE] = {8, 16, 24};

for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    losingPositionsX[i] = VALUES[i];
```

Alternatively, with `memcpy()`,

```
// Assuming VALUES has same type and size as losingPositions
memcpy(losingPositionsX, VALUES, sizeof(VALUES));
// Same thing
memcpy(losingPositionsX, VALUES, sizeof(losingPositionsX));
// Same thing (but don't use this one)
memcpy(losingPositionsX, VALUES, sizeof(int) * 3);
```

Since you are on OS X, which supports C99, you can use compound literals:

```
memcpy(losingPositionsX, (int[3]){8, 16, 24}, sizeof(losingPositionsX));
```

The loop is the safest, and will probably be optimized into the same machine code as `memcpy()` by the compiler.  It's relatively easy to make typos with `memcpy()`.

Answer (score 1):

In C (and by extension, in Objective C) you cannot assign C arrays to each other like that. You copy C arrays with `memcpy`, like this:

```
int losingPositionsX[] = {0, 4, 8};
memcpy(losingPositionsX, (int[3]){8, 16, 24}, sizeof(losingPositionsX));
```

**Important:** this solution requires that the sizes of the two arrays be equal.

Comment: The sizes of the arrays will probably not be equal, could I put: sizeof(someNumber) with someNumber being a different size than losingPositionsX?

Comment: @RedBadger `sizeof(someNumber)` would give you wrong results. If you want to copy `someNumber` of integers, use `sizeof(int)*someNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know, whether it is a help for you in relation to memory management. But you can do

```
int * losingPositionsX = (int[]){ 0, 4, 8 };
losingPositionsX = (int[]){ 8, 16,  32 };
```